# How to pass a variable to an imported function implicitly in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.6, implicit

`module1` defines `function1` and `function2`. `module2` makes use of the 2 functions defined in `module1` and needs to pass what can be described as a context configuration parameter (an instance of a mutable custom class actually, not something humble like a string) to them, the same every single time any of these functions get called within `module2`. I would appreciate if I could avoid using the ordinary function argument way to pass it repeatedly and could just specify it once so all the functions called within the module (`module2`) would be able to access it. Is this possible in Python? I use the latest Python 3.6. `module1` is not a 3-rd party library nor an established codebase module, I can modify the definitions whatever way necessary at this stage.

```
# --- module1.py ---

class Context:
    def __init__(self, s: str):
        self.s = s


def function1(cx: Context, s1: str):
    print(f'{cx.s} {s1}!')


# --- module2.py ---

from module1 import Context
from module1 import function1

cx = Context('Hello')

# this works and prints 'Hello World!'
function1(cx, 'World')


# this doesn't work but I want it to work and do exactly the same
# (function1 definition can be changed whatever way necessary)
function1('World')
```

Comment: Can you show some code to make it more clear what you mean?

Comment: Sure. Maybe show something you have now and would like to know how to replace it.

Comment: It sounds like you want something like dynamic scoping, which Python doesn't support. You can maybe hack something together, but I suspect, you should rather redesign this approach to make use of a class that takes this configuration objects as a parameter and encapsulates that state there, rather than rely on global variables.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I've added the code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do this with a module-level global variable.

```
context = None

def function1(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    # do something involving context and args
```

Then you just do `module1.context = whatever` from where you've imported `module1`.

But a better approach is a class that holds a reference to the context, passed in when the object is instantiated:

```
class MyFunctions(object):
    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context
    def function1(self, arg1, arg2. arg3):
        # do something with self.context and args
```

Then you use it like this:

```
 myfunctions = MyFunctions(configuration_object)
 myfunctions.function1(1, 2, 3)
```

This way, you can have as many contexts as you need.

Comment: Using a class is an obvious solution but there will be many functions and they are going to be long and mutually-independent, sharing nothing but one variable (in fact I would be glad to put every function in a separate file, perhaps I will make a package), the class is not going to represent a logically real entity, and... a major reason why I choose Python is that I can define a function without a class :-)

Comment: They share state (that one variable) and if you don't want to pass it to each function, it's perfectly reasonable to put them in a class.

Comment: The answer I was looking for is `module1.context = whatever`. What I've tried before was `from module1 import *` and then `context = whatever` and it didn't work. Now I `import module1` then set `module1.context = whatever` and then `from module1 import *` and everything seems working fine. Tanks!

Answer (score 2):

(Edited to match the sample code from the question) This may be a nice place for a partial, if you modify your function to make `cx` a keyword argument (or, alternatively, the last positional argument) like so:

```
def function1(s1: str, cx: Context = None):
    print(f'{cx.s} {s1}!')
```

Then you can do:

```
from module1 import Context
from module1 import function1
from functools import partial
cx = Context('hello')
function1 = partial(function1, cx = cx)
```

And when you call `function1`, you'll be calling the partial, which already has the `cx` argument set.

Comment: You could even provide a function in the module that, given the context option, returns partials of all the functions in one fell swoop. The caller then sets up their own names for the functions, like `function1, function2, ... = module1.partials(cx)`

Comment: Great answer (though too verbose for my case as I have a lot of the functions). I wish I could approve both.

Comment: @kindall sounds curious. How can this possibly be done (I am just beginning Python, sorry if a stupid question)?

Comment: Something like `def givecontext(cx): return partial(function1, cx=cx), partial(function2, cx=cx), partial(function3, cx=cx)`. Then the caller would just do `func1, func2, func3 = givecontext(Context("foo"))`

Answer (score 2):

A completely different approach, and probably a *terrible, terrible* idea, but fun (and avoids most of the legwork in `module2`): you could make a decorator that finds `cx` in the caller's context and supplies it to the function automatically. Like so:

```
import sys
from functools import wraps

def withCallerContext(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*a, **k):
        frame = sys._getframe(0)
        while 'cx' not in frame.f_globals:
            frame = frame.f_back
            if frame is None:
                raise ValueError("must set cx in calling context")

        cx = frame.f_globals['cx']
        return fn(*a, cx = cx, **k)
    return wrapped


@withCallerContext
def function1(s1: str, cx: Context = None):
    print(f'{cx.s} {s1}!')
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, that is a nice (evil) hack.

Comment: You could also just have a function `getcontext()` that you call from each function to get the caller's `cx` variable.